# Manage the roster list, xmppFramework

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I delete user from roster list with code:

```
   XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    _currentDelete = user.jidStr;
    [[[self appDelegate] xmppRoster ]removeUser: [XMPPJID jidWithString: _currentDelete]];
```

Then I do it the user A who delete an user B is deleting from user B roster list. Is there way to delete user A from user B roster list and not delete user B self from user A roster list?

Answer (score 0):

When a user A removes an user B, it sends to B an "unsubscribed" presence.

So, to remove A from B roster list

```
if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"unsubscribed"]) {

    [xmppRoster removeUser:[presence from]];

}
```

Hope that helps :D